# How can I retrieve images from folder whose name are stored in database?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-Q02V0BS\AQ;Initial Catalog=upload_file;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select filename from file_table",con);
        SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            Response.Write("<img src=&quot;" + Server.MapPath("~/Images/")+ r[0].ToString()+"&quot;/>");
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

I have saved the image name into a table which is `file_table`and the column name is `filename`. When I click on this button no image is generated using current image path.

Comment: What error are you getting? Does your code throw exception any where?

Comment: Try replacing both `&quot;` in your `Response.Write` line with `\"` as I'm not sure the quotes need to be HTML encoded.

Comment: I Tried but /" does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the image object and then modifying its properties.  In my example I created a div that I can add the images to.

demo.aspx:

```
<div id="imageContainer" runat="server"></div>
```

demo.aspx.cs

```
HtmlImage myImage = new HtmlImage();
string myImagePath;

myImagePath = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
myImage.Src = myImagePath;

imageContainer.Controls.Add(myImage);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir you solved my problem. May I show you code ?

Comment: @Abdul I'm glad I was able to help.  Since my answer solved your problem, please mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Abdul, I'm not sure what you mean by "may I show you code".  You are free to share my code with anyone.